# Group a csv duplicate column

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am kind of stuck with grouping and exporting a csv column with duplicate values of daily machine status. There will be only two duplicate values per machine.

```
hostname  status   
ABC         up      
DEF         up      
GHI         down    
ABC         down    
DEF         up      
GHI         up
```

I am looking to get

```
hostname  status_morning   status_evening
ABC          up               down 
DEF          up                 up
GHI          down               up
```

```
$groups = import-csv .\machine-status.csv | group-object hostname
foreach($group in $groups){
Select-Object @{Name='Hostname'   ;Expression={$_.Values[0]}},
               @{Name='status_morning';Expression={$_.Values[1]}},
              @{Name='status_evening' ;Expression={$_.Values[2]}}

}
```

Comment: You need something feeding into select object; maybe `$group.group | Select-Object ...`

Comment: You can pipe into `Select-Object` from `group-object` -> `group-object hostname | select-object ...`. You don't need the `foreach` statement. Your expressions will be retrieving data from the `Group` property. So use `$_.Group[0].Hostname`,`$_.Group[0].Status`, and `$_.Group[1].status` respectively.

Comment: Can the `GroupInfo` collections be guaranteed to maintain any known order? How to be sure `status_morning` and `status_evening` are grouped in the expected order? Is there any chance of seeing a third entry for any of the hosts?

Comment: @AdminOfThings.. I am getting the below ```import-csv .\host.csv | group-object hostname | Select-Object  $_.Group[0].Hostname
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ import-csv .\hoist.csv | group-object hostname | Select-Object  $_.Gr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray```

Comment: @stringfellow .. the host entry will have only two duplicate host entry with first one of morning and last of evening status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be other simple ways, but the following code works.

```
$csv = Import-csv C:\PS\stack.csv | Group-Object 'HostName'
$csv | Select-Object 'Name',@{ n='Morning_status';e={$_.Group.status[0]}},@{ n='Evening_status';e={$_.Group.status[1]}}
```